# reactnative IllegalViewOperationException: Unable to execute operation dispatchViewManagerCommand on view with tag: 1909 since the view does not exist

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code and getting this error only on my android device: IllegalViewOperationException: Unable to execute operation dispatchViewManagerCommand on view with tag: 1909 since the view does not exist

If user types to the input field and press next than the error occurs.
If the input field is empty, and when I click next than no error.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
const TestScreen = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 30,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        position: 'relative',
      }}
    >
      {page === 0 && (
        <View>
          <TextInput placeholder='Title' />
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setPage(page + 1)}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>press</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      )}
      {page === 1 && (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Hello</Text>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setPage(page - 1)}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>press</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
export default TestScreen;
```

android version 11

packages:
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.11.0",
"@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
"@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.2",
"@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.0",
"@react-native-community/viewpager": "3.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^10.1.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.827.0",
"axios": "^0.21.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.3",
"date-fns": "^2.21.3",
"expo": "~38.0.8",
"expo-av": "~8.2.1",
"expo-blur": "^9.0.3",
"expo-constants": "~9.1.1",
"expo-error-recovery": "~1.2.1",
"expo-file-system": "~9.0.1",
"expo-firebase-analytics": "~2.4.1",
"expo-font": "~8.2.1",
"expo-image-picker": "~8.3.0",
"expo-linear-gradient": "^8.2.2",
"expo-notifications": "~0.3.3",
"expo-permissions": "~9.0.1",
"expo-screen-orientation": "~1.1.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "^0.5.0",
"expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
"expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
"expo-video-player": "^1.6.1",
"firebase": "^8.1.1",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"react": "~16.11.0",
"react-aws-s3": "^1.3.0",
"react-dom": "~16.11.0",
"react-native": "~0.62.2",
"react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1260.0",
"react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-easy-content-loader": "^0.3.2",
"react-native-elements": "^3.0.0-alpha.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
"react-native-head-tab-view": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-looped-carousel-improved": "^1.0.2",
"react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.9",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.0.7",
"react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
"react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-scrollable-tab-view-collapsible-header": "0.0.5",
"react-native-smooth-picker": "^1.1.4",
"react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
"react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
"react-native-web": "^0.15.0",
"splash-screen": "^4.0.1",
"swr": "^0.3.11"

Comment: have you found any solution

Comment: If I remember correctly I ended up using a material-ui tab component which is customizable,  https://v3.mui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Stack Navigator was set to hidden after the global timer timeout and then set to display. I correct it by navigating to my init screen when the global timer timeout.